# Problem when trying to add PayPal gateway

Tags: paypal, laravel-8

I'm trying to add PayPal gateway to my website, and I use Laravel 8
but when I push the button get the following error. Can you help me to solve this problem, please?

> Connection timed out after 10010 milliseconds.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the section named [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.